# Edit The listbox selected text in Runtime asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have a listbox in asp.net 
I tried when user click on it's item in runtime can change the text of this item without change the order of the the items .
So I try to make Edit button when click on it get the item value 
as

```
 protected void btnEditListValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string listvalue = lstParameters.Items.IndexOf(lstParameters.SelectedItem).ToString();
            string listText = lstParameters.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
```

then I will make textbox fill value from string `listText` to enable user to edit

what shall I do after that to keep listbox order as old without delete and insert again

please help

Comment: Why do you convert the index of the selected item to string at all? What do you want to do with `listvalue`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Something wrong also , listText gets the value of the first item all the time and listvalue just for test I didn't use it

Comment: Maybe you are databinding the ListBox on every postback instead of only `if(!isPostBack){DataBindYourListBox();}`. Then all changes or events are lost.

Comment: @TimSchmelter in `if(!isPostBack)` I clear the `lstParameters.Items.Clear();` and if I remove it will autopostback and append new data on the old one

Comment: Where do you append data? You should not append items or databind the ListBox at all on postback. Or have you disabled viewstate? But of course, if you clear the items you won't have a selected item other then the first(which means none at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the [`ListItem.Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.text(v=vs.110).aspx), f.e. when the user changed the text:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(lstParameters.SelectedIndex >= 0 && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text))
   {
       ListItem selectedItem = lstParameters.Items[lstParameters.SelectedIndex];
       selectedItem.Text = TextBox1.Text;
   }
}
```